# How to disable all elements on form with rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial which includes a form, i have two different instances where i want to use this form, one if for editing and another one if for viewing only, i want to disable all of the fields in a second case. Is there any quick way to do it in rails? I know i can do it with jquery but i prefer to do it in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap all elements in `with_options :disabled => 'disabled' do` method.

Comment: thanks for that useful method, here is a video screencast on how to use it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/42-with-options

Comment: How did you do it in the view? This rails cast is talking about how to do it for the controller method.

Comment: @Encore PTL what difference? It's just ruby method with block